# Installing FFMPEG on Mac

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have tried installing ffmpeg through homebrew using

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

When I tried importing ffmpeg into Python I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ffmpeg
```

I can confirm that ffmpeg is installed through brew list.  I am not sure why python is not recognizing it.

Answer (score 8):

What you've installed is the `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` command-line tool and various C libraries. It doesn't include any Python bindings. If you want to install [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python), run `pip install --user ffmpeg-python`.